# Building Path - Google Drive SDK

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-drive-api

I'm trying to build a remote path for a file using the Python Google Drive API. Given a path, say /folderA/FolderB/folderC/theFile.txt I want to create folderA on Drive then folderB in that, then folderC in B, before uploading the file to folderC.

I have a short loop:

```
currentParent = pathStartID
for aFolder in pathArray:
    thisFoldersID = self.createRemoteFolder(aFolder, parentID = currentParent)
    currentParent = thisFoldersID
```

I first create folderA in the Drive root, and folderA's ID is 'pathStartID'. The pathArray contains folderB and folderC's names.

```
createRemoteFolder()
```

looks like this:

```
def createRemoteFolder(self, folderName, parentID = None):
    # Create a folder on Drive, returns the newely created folders ID
    body = {
        'title': folderName,
        'mimeType': "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    }
    if parentID:
        body['parentsCollection'] = [{'id': parentID}]
        root_folder = driveFileMan.client.files().insert(body = body).execute()
    return root_folder['id']
```

but for some reason every folder is being created in root of Google Drive, not in the parent folder like I want.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? Or is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like just the wrong property name for setting the parent. Try:

```
body['parents'] = [{'id': parentID}]
```

Comment: I should have spotted that - spent ages scratching my head looking at this! Great, thanks for the help, that did the trick :)